# find - Traverse all subdirectories from a starting point and check if specific subdirectory is contained in them

Tags: linux, shell, directory, find, traversal

I was looking for a way to traverse the full path (all the subdirectories) from a given starting point (current directory in my example) and then check if the full path has a directory called "xyz" in it. If it does, we do **not** print this path. We print only the full paths that lack the "xyz" subdirectiry in them after fully traversed / expanded.

Here is an example:

In the path `/root/test/1/foo/bar/xyz`, we should exclude the entire `/root/test/1/foo/bar` from output, because we have "xyz" in the "bar" subdirectory.

We should not include in the output, say, `/root/test/1/foo/bar/abc`, because while it is true that there is no "xyz" subdirectory down the "abc" one and "abc" obviously is not called "xyz", we have a "xyz" subdirectory inside `/root/test/1/foo/bar/`, so "abc" and any other subdirectories of "bar" should not be traversed further and we should go back to `foo/` and continue applying the logic to the next subdirectory of `foo/`, if there are any. If not, return one level down, and so on.

The output should not contain any partial paths either, e.g. `/root/test/1`, `/root/test/1/foo`, etc - only the full path with the last subdirectory at the end.

The best i came up with is a rather overcomplicated, partial approach:

`find "$(pwd)" -type d -not \( -path '*/xyz' -o -path '*/xyz/*' \) -exec sh -c 'for d; do (cd "$d" && test -z "$(find . -type d -name xyz -print -quit)") && echo "$d"; done' sh {} +`

However, this doesn't solve the problem when we have other subdirectories alongside the "xyz" one in `/root/test/1/foo/bar/` and it will print in the output, say, `/root/test/1/foo/bar/abc`, if there is "abc" alongside "xyz" in `bar/`.

Any ideas how to modify the one-liner to achieve the desired task? It's not mandatory to be an one-liner.

Comment: how many folder are we talking? 100s? 10,000s? 1,000,000s?

Comment: Should it be the only one `find` command or it is allowed to post-process output?

Comment: @jhnc Many folders, say 20k.

Comment: @dimich No, the solution is not limited to a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your filesystem is one of those where `-links 2` is not guaranteed to be true for leaf directories (eg. SMB, btrfs, some macOS, etc), the simple "one-liner" is:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d \
   \( -exec test -d {}/xyz \; -prune -o -links 2 -print \)
```

- if path is directory:

  - ignore it if it contains a subdirectory called `xyz`
  - else print if it has only two links (ie. `.` and from parent)

---

Otherwise, you can use similar pruning to skip searching known invalid subdirectores:

```
find "$(pwd)" \
    -type d \
        -print \
        -exec test -d {}/xyz \; \
            -exec printf '%s/xyz\n' {} \; \
            -prune
```

This walks the tree printing directories.

If a directory contains an unwanted subdirectory, it is printed (to use later in processing) but the rest of that subtree is pruned.

Output will be a list of prefix directory paths leading up to a leaf directory, or a list of prefix directory paths until an unwanted directory.

We can then filter out the prefix paths and print the rest, but only those whose leaf is not the unwanted directory:

```
... | awk -F/ -v skip="xyz" '
    NR>1 && p0"/"!=substr($0,1,length(p0)+1) {
        if (leaf!=skip) print p0
    }
    { p0 = $0; leaf=$NF }
    END { if (leaf!=skip) print p0 }
'
```

For each directory name that is read in:

- print the previous directory name (`p0`) if, with slash appended, it is not a prefix of the current directory name (`$0`), unless its leaf is the excluded directory
- save the current directory name as the previous directory name, and its leaf
- at the end, print the final directory name that was read (unless its leaf is the unwanted directory)

The `awk` script assumes directory names don't contain newlines.

Comment: the `test` used here will consider symlinks to directories to be directories

Comment: if you need to handle directory names containing newlines, some versions of `find`/`awk` allow `-print0`/`-v RS='\0'` to produce/process null-delimited records

Comment: In the context of the example above, this will also print ```/root/test/1/foo/``` and we don't want that, because down the path from this directory, we have a ```bar``` subdirectory and inside ```bar```, we have ```xyz```. So if there is ```xyz``` anywhere in the fully expanded path down to the last subdirectory, this elimates the whole path from the output.

Comment: Yup, the second solution is working just fine with standard filesystems.

Comment: I think this revision fixes the issue: the unwanted directory has to be printed so that its prefixes are not left dangling (which caused the final such to be printed by mistake)

Comment: Absolutely, i can confirm that the last version solves all the problems and essentially completes the task. The ```awk``` approach is amazing and is very fast even with a large set of directories returned by ```find```.